# "On top of that"

Tags: word-usage

> You had fennel seeds, and on top of that, you had cold water. Of course, you had to catch a cold.

(Though honestly, I don't see any logic in that, but that's not the question...)

Does "on top of that" sound natural here? I mean, it is usually used with unpleasant situations.

There was nothing bad about having fennel seeds, but the person shouldn't have had cold water after eating the fennel seeds.  So, can it be used with food?

Like you have something, and then you have another.

Comment: It's not clear that **had** in your sentence means **consumed**. It's not the best example. But, yes, you can use **on top of** in this context. **What, you had ice-cream on top of a starter, a main course and a sweet. No wonder you're feeling ill.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use "on top of that" in any situation where you're talking about adding more.  Usually used to indicate a fair degree more, but

> She had meat every night this week, and on top of that, she had iron pills.  Her anemia is improving.

is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Yes, on top of that means:plus

Comment: I would say it means "in addition to".   *She had meat every night this week, and **in addition to*** that, she had iron pills.*